# Is there a nonvirtually abelian group whose commutator subgroup is finite?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If the derived subgroup is finite, does the center have finite index?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272152/if-the-derived-subgroup-is-finite-does-the-center-have-finite-index)

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group whose commutator subgroup is finite. Is $G$ necessarily virtually abelian?

Comment: In case it'd be true then we'd have kind of opposite direction to the well known theorem that if $\,[G:Z(G)]<\infty\, $ then $\,G'\,$ is finite, yet the *exact* opposite is false, as you can see here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272152/if-the-derived-subgroup-is-finite-does-the-center-have-finite-index Whether there general case if true I still cannot say...

Comment: In fact this question was answered (by me) in 272152. The answer is yes given the assumption that $G$ is finitely generated. (And the answer to the question in the title is no! You have asked opposite questions in the title and in the body.)