# Index of centralizer if $H\lhd G$ and $|H| < \infty$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

I have read the first answer for this question [Centralizer of a finite normal subgroup has finite index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269782/centralizer-of-a-finite-normal-subgroup-has-finite-index) and I did not understood, why if $|Aut(H)| < \infty$, then $kernel = C_G(H)$ must have finite index?

Comment: Because of the reason stated there. The index of the kernel is the cardinality of the image.

Comment: Given the homomorphism $T:G\to Aut(H)$ ( In this case was the one given by conjugation T(g)h=ghg^{-1}). By the Fundamental theorem of homomorphisms tells you that $G/kernel=G/C_G(H)$ is isomorphic to the image (in this case a subgroup of $Aut(H)$, hence finite). So, $G/C_G(H)$ is finite, which means exactly that $C_G(H)$ has finite index.